# undetected_chromedriver working in full mode but failing in headless model (cloudflare)

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to open a website using undetected_chromedriver with the headless model. The website is using Cloudflare. If I am using without a headless model then the script is working but when I use headless = True it shows a captcha.

import ssl
import time
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
import os
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('website_url')
# import time
time.sleep(10)
driver.save_screenshot('sample.png')
```

Now if I set headless = True, it's showing a captcha

import ssl
import time
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
import os
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"')
options.headless = True
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('website_url')
# import time
time.sleep(10)
driver.save_screenshot('sample.png')
```

How Can I make it undetectable from cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

Add this chrome options as well.

```
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

This should prevent detection.